# Safari web inspector: view css grid

Tags: safari, css-grid

Is there a way to see the position of the grid with Safari Web Inspector like Firefox do it with grid inspector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Stretching the Metrics tab in Inspect Element's Right side pane of Elements tab will display the css box model with padding, border, margin and position. [image]</s>

If you are using Safari version 9.1, you can see it by selecting "Styles - Computed" in the Styles dropown in the Styles drawer on the right of the dev tools. (The Styles section otherwise defaults to "Styles - Visual", so you need to make the selection to make the box visible). Hope this helps.

The question was about grid inspector. There is no grid inspectors in Safari. Although Safari is noted for Safari Responsive Design mode there is no grid inspector in Safari yet.

Answer (score 1):

As of [Safari Technology Preview 123](https://webkit.org/blog/11588/introducing-css-grid-inspector/) and [Safari 15](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=kffgj3af), there is now a CSS Grid inspector.

In the Elements tab you'll find a grid button, if a grid is present.

In the Layout subtab, all grids on the page will be listed at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help clarify, the image below shows where the grid overlay can be turned on in Safari's Inspector.

[image: Safari inspector Layout tab with Grid]